# get crashed when deference subclassed NSObject

Tags: ios, iphone, nsobject

```
@interface PADiscover : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) unsigned int dw3C;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isSet;
@property (nonatomic, assign) PAContactModel model;

@end
```

In another VC

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *shakeDict;
```

Then I add some objects to shakeDict

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
            NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:message.sDeviceInfo.dw3CId];
            PADiscover *discover = [[PADiscover alloc] init];
            discover.dw3C = message.sDeviceInfo.dw3CId;
            discover.model = message.sDeviceInfo.dwDeviceType;
            discover.isSet = message.sDeviceInfo.fgPasswdFlag;

            [_shakeDict setObject:discover forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", num]];

            [_shakeTV reloadData];
 }


  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
PADiscover *discover = [[_shakeDict allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


**cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID %u, ISSet %d", discover.dw3C, discover.isSet];//crashed!**
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"model %d", discover.model];
cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11];

return cell;
}
```

It seems cannot deference **PADiscover** successfully,but I'm not sure when place I get some wrong.
can anyone explain that for me?

Comment: Don't forget that NSDictionary is not an ordered collection, so the [[_shakeDict allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; line might give you different keys than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSString *key = [[_shakeDict allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
PADiscover *discover = [_shakeDict objectForKey:key];
```

instead of

```
PADiscover *discover = (PADiscover *)[[_shakeDict allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

At least this line may be error:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) PAContactModel model;
```

change to strong if a model class.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) PAContactModel model;
```